# Is there a difference between an organizer and inducer substance?

Tags: terminology, development, embryology

There is a question in my Embryology textbook's exercise that asks about an organizer and inducer substance. I found their definitions and now I am wondering if they are the same things?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/organizer) they are synonyms:

> [An **organizer** is]  a region of a developing embryo or a substance produced by such a region that is capable of inducing a specific type of development in undifferentiated tissue —called also **inductor**

[Lifemap](http://discovery.lifemapsc.com/library/review-of-medical-embryology/chapter-27-general-mechanisms-of-normal-development) and [Biology Today](http://www.biology-today.com/embryology/organiser-concept-in-embryology/) support the terms being synonymous as well.

However, I think the most commonly used terminology here is that the **organizer** [used as a noun] **induces** [used as a verb] the differentiation of embryonic tissue. For example, consider the following quote ([Arizona State University](https://embryo.asu.edu/pages/spemann-mangold-organizer)):

> The Spemann-Mangold organizer, also known as the Spemann organizer, is
>   a cluster of cells in the developing embryo of an amphibian that
>   induces development of the central nervous system